# ko.computed cannot access observables when declared inside a closure function

Tags: knockout.js, closures, computed-observable

I have created the following model and I don't understand why the pureComputed observable **ApprovalIconCSS** cannot access the Approved() observable from its function context.

```
function KOViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.IsAdding = ko.observable(false);
    self.IsEnabled = ko.observable(true);
    self.ApprovalType = ko.observable(0);

    var RowControl = function() {
        return {
            Approved: ko.observable(null),
            ApproverNotes: ko.observable(''),
            ApprovalIconCSS: ko.pureComputed(function() {
                if (this.Approved() == 0)
                    return 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle';
                if (this.Approved() == 1)
                    return 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle';
                if (this.Approved() == 2)
                    return 'glyphicon glyphicon-time';
                return '';
            }, this)
        };
    };

    self.RowControls = ko.observableArray([RowControl()]);
}
```

Appreciate if someone can shed light why the context isn't accessible. Cheers!

Comment: By the way, you aren't using any closures in your above code, despite the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `RowControls` with `new`, and you need to attach the properties to the `this` object of the `RowControl` function, rather than returning a different object.

```
var RowControl = function() {
    this.Approved = ko.observable(null);
    this.ApproverNotes = ko.observable('');
    this.ApprovalIconCSS = ko.pureComputed(function() {
        if (this.Approved() == 0)
            return 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle';
        if (this.Approved() == 1)
            return 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle';
        if (this.Approved() == 2)
            return 'glyphicon glyphicon-time';
        return '';
    }, this)
};

self.RowControls = ko.observableArray([new RowControl()]);
```

The problem returning a literal object is that `ko.pureComputed` is being called with the `this` object, and if you return a different object, rather than adding properties to `this`, then the `this` object, and the result of `new RowControl()` (i.e. the object that has an "Approved" property) are two different objects.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation Retsam! Are returning literals evil?

Comment: It's not evil; but there's limits on what you can do with returning a literal (or rather, some things, like this, get more awkward returning a literal), so personally I've just gotten in the habit of modifying `this`.

Comment: Plus, using `this` lets you mix exposed and not exposed properties together; which you can't do just returning a literal object.

Comment: thanks, guess I'll have to rewrite this module as this limits usage of computed observables